# convert a list of strings that i would like to convert to a list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list

i have a list of strings that i would like to convert to a list of tuples. Below is an example.

```
['(0, "ass\'")', "(-1, '\\n       print self.amount')", "(0, '\\n\\n  ')"]
```

to be converted to.

```
[(0, "ass\'"), (-1, '\\n       print self.amount'), (0, '\\n\\n  ')]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[ast.literal_eval(x) for x in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map(ast.literal_eval, list_of_tuple_strings)
```

Unlike `eval`, ast.literal_eval will only evaluate literals, not function calls, so it much more secure.

Answer (score 0):

The function eval is what you need I think, but be careful with its use:

```
>>> l = ['(0, "ass\'")', "(-1, '\\n       print self.amount')", "(0, '\\n\\n  ')"]

>>> map(eval, l)
[(0, "ass'"), (-1, '\n       print self.amount'), (0, '\n\n  ')]
```

Comment: `eval` is not safe, but `literal_eval` is.