# Converting a string of tuples to a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python

How can I convert `"[(5, 2), (1,3), (4,5)]"` into a list of tuples 
`[(5, 2), (1,3), (4,5)]`

I am using `planetlab` shell that does not support `"import ast"`. So I am unable to use it.

Comment: For the 1230123012312th time: `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @JBernardo: Maybe that should be an answer?

Comment: I am using planetlab shell that does not support "import ast". SO I am unable to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert a list of strings that i would like to convert to a list of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230274/convert-a-list-of-strings-that-i-would-like-to-convert-to-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: @Parikshit Then a plain `eval` won't help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is unavailable, you can use the (unsafe!) [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval):

```
>>> s = "[(5, 2), (1,3), (4,5)]"
>>> eval(s)
[(5, 2), (1, 3), (4, 5)]
```

However, you should really overthink your serialization format. If you're transferring data between Python applications and need the distinction between tuples and lists, use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). Otherwise, use [**JSON**](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Comment: I see if s = "[('a', 2), ('b',3), ('c',5)]" result is [(a, 2), (b, 3), (c, 5)]

Comment: @Slim_user71169 That's not true in any Python I know of. Can you post a link to an online interpreter that shows the problem, [like this](http://ideone.com/5jbz8O)?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't trust the source of the string enough to use `eval`, then use `re`.

```
import re
tuple_rx = re.compile("\((\d+),\s*(\d+)\)")
result = []
for match in tuple_rx.finditer("[(5, 2), (1,3), (4,5)]"):
  result.append((int(match.group(1)), int(match.group(2))))
```

The code above is very straightforward and only works with 2-tuples of integers. If you want to parse more complex structures, you're better off with a proper parser.

Answer (score 1):

['join'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) replace following characters '()[] ' and creates string of comma separated numbers

`5,2,1,3,4,5`

['split'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits that string on ',' and creates list strings

`['5','2','1','3','4','5']`

['iter'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter) creates iterator that will go over list of elements

and the last line uses a list comprehension using ['zip'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#zip) to group together two numbers

```
it = iter("".join(c for c in data if c not in "()[] ").split(","))
result = [(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in zip(it, it)]

>>> [(5, 2), (1, 3), (4, 5)]
```