# Convert unicoded list of tuples of a dataframe row to a processiable/iterable format

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Here is my code snippet where I am trying to process a column of a pandas dataframe

```
def langprob(lid_set):
    print lid_set, type(lid_set)
    return 

df['ls']= df.apply(lambda row: langprob(row['lid']), axis=1)
```

And I am getting the output as follows:

```
[(fi, 0.8201195597648621, 90), (fy, 0.627633810043335, 4)], <type 'unicode'>
```

While I want to process the tuples inside the list one by one by iterating, I am not sure how to proceed from here.

How can I iterate or convert the unicode`[(fi, 0.8201195597648621, 90), (fy, 0.627633810043335, 4)]` to an iterable? I am sure there is an easy way, but I am missing some basics.

P.S: I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715893/how-to-convert-a-string-of-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-python-list-of-tuples) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935680/converting-a-string-of-tuples-to-a-list-of-tuples-in-python) SO answers. They weren't of much help!

Comment: If you're talking about converting string -> object, we have questions for that already. See the bottom of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48008191/4909087

Comment: @coldspeed I have tried that option,  and I get `AttributeError: ("'unicode' object has no attribute 'apply'", u'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: I mean `import ast; df['iid'] = df['iid'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: @coldspeed I have tried that as well, I get `ValueError: malformed string`

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Your string is malformed, parsing it is non-trivial.